# How to retrieve information from another website?

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to retrieve some information from other website to my website(Legally)... I am new in ASP Classic and XML DOM. I know XML DOM but not having enough knowledge to use it. I am using below code to get page from other website, and its working fine

```
Dim xml
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", "http://www.midwayusa.com/Product/"&sCode  , false
xml.Send
Dim strRetrive
strRetrive=xml.responseText
```

Now, Problem is to get Status of Product this page. I have seen Source Code of this page, and it follows below :

```
 <div id="status_block">
            <span id="persistentStatus">Status:</span>
                <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
            <div id="productStatus">
                Available
                <a class="helpicon mimo" title="Available" href="/Content/htm/Legacy/product_status.htm#200">
                </a>
            </div>
   .....
```

I want to get Value from DIV id = productStatus. 
As I know, Can I use XPath Query or other tool? If So, can you give me more info on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHTTP is going to get you the full text.  Thats just the way that it works.  Usually if you have control on the site you are requesting then you make sure what the server returns is minimal.  Its useful when using XMLHTTP to request JSON, or XML data that you can later reuse.

If you are doing scraping, from a site where you have zero control over.  Then you are stuck with HTML as the returned response.   What you have to do is use vbscripts string functions such as replace and split to remove all the text before the div id="productStatus" and if you know there are no more nested divs then you can get rid of everything after the /div> closing tag.   That leaves you with only that div in your string.

Every situation is different, but get used to the idea of using string functions to clean up the data and trim it down to what is useful to you.

Comment: Its a complete pain in the arse.  The problem with scraping sites is that they often change.  Another approach might be to scrape using jquery which has selectors.  I guess you can first scrape the whole thing into a div, then use jquery to target the div, and then do an ajax post.  Its not pretty.